# iOS Delegate Not Working

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, uibutton, protocols

Basically, I have two UIViewControllers, there are some buttons in one of them. Once the user touches the button in one of the View Controllers, I want to trigger some actions in another view controller. But it seems not working somehow. Basically, the "if" condition which is:

```
if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(userDidTouchButtons:)])
        {
            [self.delegate userDidTouchButtons:self];
        }
```

seems not working, because the `[self.delegate respondToSelector]`is always false.

This is the .h file of the first view controller, which has some buttons.
    #import

```
@class RightSideMenuViewController;

@protocol RightSideMenuDelegate <NSObject>

- (void) userDidTouchButtons: (RightSideMenuViewController *) rightMenuViewController;

@end

@interface RightSideMenuViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, assign) id <RightSideMenuDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

This is the .m file of the first view controller.

```
- (IBAction)badmintonClicked:(UIButton *)sender
{   
    if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(userDidTouchButtons:)])
    {
        [self.delegate userDidTouchButtons:self];
    }
}
```

This is the .m file of the second view controller, where I want to trigger the action here, according to the buttons in the first view controller.

```
#import "RightSideMenuViewController.h"

@interface DiscoverTimelineTableViewController () <RightSideMenuDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) RightSideMenuViewController *rightMeuViewController;
@end
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad]; 
    self.rightMeuViewController.delegate = self;
}

#pragma mark - RIGHT MENU Delegate methods
- (void) userDidTouchButtons: (RightSideMenuViewController *) rightMenuViewController
{
    NSLog(@"He touches me!!!");
}
```

Comment: make sure self.rightMeuViewController this is not nill before this line  self.rightMeuViewController.delegate = self;

Comment: where is rightMeuViewController intialise?

Comment: the problem is you are not setting the delegate
    self.rightMeuViewController.delegate = self;// this will be nil, 
, how DiscoverTimelineTableViewController appears, it is in navigation or modal presented or another tab?

Comment: @RaheelSadiq Actually I use the library "SWRevealViewController" to make a side menu, and the rightMenuViewController is the side menu on the right hand side.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the `delegate` is properly set, i.e., `self.rightMeuViewController` should not be nil

it seems like you are not setting the `rightMeuViewController` property while navigating to second view controller